# Paste colnames by sequence

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr, na, paste

Hi and happy new year at all.

I have a tricky task (in my opinion) and I can not find a way to solve it.
Please see following toy data. The orginal dataset has hundreds of cols/rows.

```
test<-data.frame(name=c("Amber","Thomas","Stefan","Zlatan"),
             US=c(8,2,NA,7),
             UK=c(5,4,1,7))
```

I want to create a new column, called "origin", which pastes the colname of each cell (without NA) seperated by "|" under consideration of the corresponding value. Higher values should be pasted first. As for same values (like Zlatan), the sequence isn´t relevant. Output for Zlatan could be US|UK OR UK|US.

This is the desired ouput:

[image]

I tried some hours to solve it but no approach worked. May be it make sense to convert the values as.factor...

Help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` approach. First, we can use `rowwise` to work on individual rows independently. Next, we can use `c_across` which allows us to select values from that row only. We can subset a vector of `c("US","UK")` based on whether the `US` and `UK` columns are not `NA`.

`paste` with `collapse = "|"` allows us to put the values together with the seperator. I added a row to see what would happen if they are both `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(origin = paste(c("US","UK")[rev(order(c_across(US:UK), na.last = NA))], collapse = "|"))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Rowwise: 
  name      US    UK origin 
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
1 Amber      8     5 "US|UK"
2 Thomas     2     4 "UK|US"
3 Stefan    NA     1 "UK"   
4 Zlatan     7     7 "UK|US"
5 Bob       NA    NA ""
```

This is also trivially expanded to more columns:

```
test<-data.frame(name=c("Amber","Thomas","Stefan","Zlatan","Bob"),
                 US=c(8,2,NA,7,NA),
                 UK=c(5,4,1,7,NA),
                 AUS=c(1,2,NA,NA,1))

test %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(origin = paste(c("US","UK","AUS")[rev(order(c_across(US:AUS), na.last = NA))], collapse = "|"))
# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Rowwise: 
  name      US    UK   AUS origin   
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    
1 Amber      8     5     1 US|UK|AUS
2 Thomas     2     4     2 UK|AUS|US
3 Stefan    NA     1    NA UK       
4 Zlatan     7     7    NA UK|US    
5 Bob       NA    NA     1 AUS
```

Or with tidyselect assistance to perform all columns but `name`:

```
test %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(origin = paste(names(across(-name))[rev(order(c_across(-name), na.last = NA))], collapse = "|"))
```

Comment: Proposed modification to this because OP requested that the higher value be first in `origin`:  Replace your mutate line with `mutate(origin = paste(c("US","UK")[rev(order(c_across(US:UK), na.last = NA))], collapse = "|"))`. This will give you the reverse order of the vector, and remove the NA entries.

Comment: It looks really nice, thank you @Ian and also at qdread. This works for this example. But I have more countries and may not know about which countries will be in the data. So I added Denmark to the data. test<-data.frame(name=c("Amber","Thomas","Stefan","Zlatan","Bob"),
                 US=c(8,2,NA,7,NA),
                 UK=c(5,4,1,7,NA),
                 AUS=c(1,2,NA,NA,1),
                 DK=c(NA,NA,1,2,3))

Comment: I saved the colnames: country_colnames<-colnames(test[,-1])
and modified the mutate statement: test %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(origin = paste(country_colnames[rev(order(c_across(all_of(country_colnames)), na.last = NA))], collapse = "|"))

Comment: @crm_analytics That is a good approach, I was trying to come up with a way to get the column names with tidyselect and finally settled on using both `across` and `c_across`.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility with `tidyverse`. It is longer than the other two solutions, but it should work directly with a dataframe with as many columns as you need.

I changed the dataframe to long format, filtered out NAs, grouped by name, summarized using paste, and joined with the original dataframe to get the original columns (and rows with all NAs).

```
library(tidyverse)

test<-data.frame(name=c("Amber","Thomas","Stefan","Zlatan","Bob"),
                 US=c(8,2,NA,7,NA),
                 UK=c(5,4,1,7,NA),
                 AUS=c(1,2,NA,NA,1))
test %>%
  # change to long format
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols=-name, names_to = "country", values_to = "value") %>%
  # remove rows with NA
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  # group by name and sort
  dplyr::group_by(name) %>% dplyr::arrange(-value) %>%
  # create summary of countries for each name in column 'origin'
  dplyr::summarise(origin=paste(country, collapse = "|")) %>%
  # join with original data frame to include original columns (and names with only NA) and change NA to '' in origin
  dplyr::right_join(test, by='name') %>% dplyr::mutate(origin=ifelse(is.na(origin), '', origin)) %>%
  # move origin column to end
  dplyr::relocate(origin, .after = last_col())
```

Result

```
name      US    UK   AUS origin   
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    
1 Amber      8     5     1 US|UK|AUS
2 Bob       NA    NA     1 AUS      
3 Stefan    NA     1    NA UK       
4 Thomas     2     4     2 UK|US|AUS
5 Zlatan     7     7    NA US|UK
```

Comment: This does excactly what was requested! Thank you, also for the nice comments.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different `tidyverse` solution using `case_when`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
data <- data.frame (test<-data.frame(
    "name" =c("Amber","Thomas","Stefan","Zlatan"),
    "US" =c(8,2,NA,7),
    "UK" =c(5,4,1,7)))

data <- data %>% mutate(origin = case_when( US >  UK ~ "US|UK", 
                                    UK >= US ~ "UK|US",
                                    is.na(UK) & !is.na(US) ~ "US", 
                                    is.na(US) & !is.na(UK) ~ "UK"))
data
#>     name US UK origin
#> 1  Amber  8  5  US|UK
#> 2 Thomas  2  4  UK|US
#> 3 Stefan NA  1     UK
#> 4 Zlatan  7  7  UK|US
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Mario, thank you. This works on this example but will not work on more countries.

Comment: Indeed I like the 'collapse' solution as well. That's why it is always good to include in the question how the true dataset differs from the sample data.